# How to Use Host Root Directory in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, request, cpanel

I Want To Redirect All a Subdomain Requests To PHP File in public_html With Using .htaccess File.
But I Receive Not Found Request.
My Code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/asr/public_html/Test/index.php?path=%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [NC,L,QSA]
```

My Request Url:

```
sub.domain.com
```

Received Error:

```
Can Not Find The File!
/home/asr/sub.domain.com/home/asr/public_html/Test/index.php
```

Comment: Something is strange here. That error message you posted certainly is none that the http server generates. Please be precise in posting the actual information you have.

Comment: The rewriting rule probably should be something like `RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/?$ /Test/index.php?path=%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [L,QSA]` ... And you need a condition to prevent an endless rewriting loop. The target path inside a rewriting rule is _not_ an absolute path inside the server side file system, but inside the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of the http host!

Comment: My Htaccess File Is In The Main Host Directory. So That I Can Apply The Settings To All Domains.